# fopen producing NULL file pointer Solaris

Tags: c++, solaris, libcurl

I'm trying to make a callback function, and then write the content retrieved into a file using `libcurl`. The program works nicely in `Linux` and `Windows`, however, the `fopen` operation fails in `solarix_x86`. `myvector` contains a list of url files to be copied, and `PATH_SEPARATOR` is a macro which formats the string path, depending on the platform (`Unix`, `Windows`).

```
  vector<string>::iterator it;

  for( it=myvector.begin() ; it < myvector.end(); it++ ){
      string dest = "/home/files/" + PATH_SEPARATOR + *it // PATH_SEPARATOR IS A MACRO
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, it->c_str());
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURL_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

      file = fopen(dest.c_str(), "w+b");
      if(file == NULL){
          throw std::runtime_error("FILE IS NULL, CAN'T OPEN\n");
      }

      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, file);
      curl_easy_perform(curl);
      fclose(file);
  }
```

And function `write_data`:

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream){
     size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE*)stream);
     return written;
}
```

I'm suspecting is something related to the `"w+b"` flag.... Any thoughts?

****************** *UPDATE* ****************

`errno=2`.

Comment: `'w+b'` should be `"w+b"`. Single quotes = character constant. Double quotes = string constant.

Comment: @BoBTFish
I've changed it to "w+b", and I had the same problem

Comment: do you have write permission in the folder?

Comment: @Rolle Yes, the program works correctly in `Windows` and `Lunix`. The problem only happens in `Solaris`

Comment: Try using perror()/strerror() to get a textual description of the error. Also, "/" works as a path separator everywhere, even on DOS and Windows; the command prompt and Explorer are the only 2 programs that deliberately forbid "/" in paths. My guess is, you are either building an incorrect path, or don't have write permissions to the file or parent directory, as Rolle said.

Comment: @DanielKO when i print `strerror(errno)` I get:
`no such file or directory`. However, Does not the option `"w+b"` create the path for me?

Comment: @BoBTFish `curl` is responsible for the `http` call which retrieves the files from a remote server. Could you download the `curl` package and install it?

Comment: @DanielKO: The path has this format:
`/home/files/import/<machinename>/`. `import` and `<machinename>` aren't created until there is some files to be copied.

Comment: So do you create directories `import` and `<machinename>` beforehand or do you expect `fopen()` to create directories too?

Comment: To be clear, "w+" will cause `fopen()` to create the file if necessary. But it won't create the missing directories in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse characters and character arrays: You want `"w+b"`. Mind the quotation marks.

A good (or 'properly operated') compiler should have warned you about the fact that you are using a "multibyte character constant" (namely your `'w+b'`), which is an obscure feature of C++ that almost never makes sense.

Comment: I've changed it to "w+b", and I had the same problem

Comment: Same output ... it did not change a bit.

Comment: @philippe: Can you include the value of `dest` in your exception and check that it's sane?

Comment: `dest = /home/files/import/pineapplevm2/000000_IMAGE_REC` which is correct.

Comment: @philippe: long shot: Are the file permissions correct for the user and group as which your program runs?

Comment: Running the program as `"root"` fixed the problem

Comment: @philippe: That may be a quick-fix, but you should probably figure out a way to have your files accessible without privileges...